# Is it possible to separate either father or mother chromosomes from a sperm?

Tags: genetics, reproduction, chromosome

If we were to use a flow cytometry, can it separate either the father or mother chromosomes from a sperm?

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE. I thought I understood the question but after our discussion in the comments under my answer, I see that I actually don't understand what you mean. Can you please expand your post to clarify your question? In the meantime, I am voting to close as unclear.

Comment: There are no "mother chromosomes" in a sperm since the sperm comes from the father.  If you mean the mother of the sperm donor, there are no "mother chromosomes" because each chromosome is in general a mix of DNA from the father and the mother.

Comment: @mgkrebbs but we have 46 chromosomes from both father and mother right?So the sperm should contain 46 chromosomes can you seperate the another 23 chromosomes from the sperm?

Answer (score 1):

> If we were to use a flow cytometry, can it separate either the father or mother chromosomes from a sperm?

A sperm is [haploid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ploidy). It contains either `Y` or `X` but not `XY` or `XX`.

[Sperm sorting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sperm_sorting) is the process of sorting sperm cells based on specific trait of interest. Whether the sperm is carrying a `X` or a `Y` chromosome is definitely of interest to many.

There are a number of methods for sperm sorting (see [wiki > sperm sorting > methods](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sperm_sorting#Methods)), one of which is indeed [flow cytometry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sperm_sorting#Flow_cytometry). Flow cytometry is typically used to separate `X` bearing sperms form `Y` bearing sperms. You should typically have a look at Beltsfield Sperm Sexing Technology ([Johson et al. 1999](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/15526798)).

Comment: I'm actually asking can we seperate those xy or xx chromosome that carry genes?

Comment: I mean the autosomes from the father or mother chromosomes

Comment: I don't understand.... Do you mean whether we can separate sperms carrying the grandmother haplotype or the grandfather haplotype? Note that segregation and recombination make that gametes carry some mixture of the two grandparents haplotypes. (Here by grandparent, I refer to the parents of the male producing the sperm). Btw, is there any reason you talk about sperms and not ovules?

Comment: I asking is it possible to empty all the chromosomes genes from the father or mother from the sperm to have either father or mother chromosomes?

Comment: The expression `chromosomes genes` is unclear and suggest that you don't really understand what a gene. I am still a bit unsure of what you are asking but you can't tell what chromosome come from which grandparent (whether in a sperm cell, in an ovule or in a zygote), the main reason being that recombination shuffled them up together.

Comment: if we use flow cytometry can seperate the autosomes and the sex chromosomes of the father or mother from the sperm?

Comment: I am not sure what you call mother and father. I suppose it is what I call grandfather and grandmother, right? The answer (but I am not sure I understand what you're asking) is 'no' because it makes no sense due to [recombination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genetic_recombination). Even if there was no recombination, you could not because the only eventual difference between maternally inherited and paternally inherited chromosomes are epigenetic modifications (which flow cytometry won't help you to distinguish).

Comment: You are repeating the same question over and over but I still don't get it! Try to write more than a one line question. Give some context and maybe I will be able to understand what you're trying to ask. I think your question makes no sense (but might be wrong) but I can't tell what is your misunderstanding as long as you limit your phrasing to a single one liner question.

Comment: Sorry you seem confused,I will ask one more time Can sperm sorting empty either all the father or mothers genes from a sample of sperm?

Comment: I will answer one more time then :) Assuming that by mother and father you are referring to the parents of the male who produced the sperm (but you still have not explained what you actually meant by mother and father), then the answer is 'no' 1) because, obviously, flow cytometry is not able to brake and recombine chromosomes to undo what recombination just did and 2) the only potential markers of whether a chromosome comes from the 'mother' or the 'father' is a few epigenetic differences that can't be detected via flow cytometry. I'm out repeating that now! Good luck Daniel!